# iPhone App:Plot a graph

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-plot

In my iPhone App I want to add Graph as shown below

[image]!

How can I plot this kind of graph in my iphone App using coreplot

please Help and Suggest

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need 3 plots--two bar plots and a scatter plot. The "Year x" labels on the x-axis are easy if you set up the `labelFormatter` correctly.

Look at the example programs provided with Core Plot for ideas on how to get started.

Comment: Thanks for reply is there any tutorial which explains all properties related to scatter plot

Comment: If you installed the downloadable SDK package, you should have documentation in the Xcode help viewer. Otherwise, see http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/DocumentationPolicy for instructions on how to install Doxygen and how to set it up to build the docs. You can also view the documentation comments in the source code for CPPlot and CPScatterPlot.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this tutorial -

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application

you can also use google's graph api -

http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/